# postgres create an index

Tags: postgresql

I am going from mysql to postgres and I am having a problem creating an index.

CREATE INDEX pointsloc ON table USING gist (point_col);

This is the response I get back:

ERROR:  data type point has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.

I have seen I need to specify the operator class for the index, different classes can be used depending upon the type of operators you wish to use on the column. I wish to use the @> or ~ to find if a point is within a polygon.

How do i specify the operator class?? help please has to be a simple thing but I am stumped!

**EDIT**

Below is a print screen of me trying to add an index to the branch table:

```
                                   Table "public.branch"
      Column      |       Type       |                      Modifiers                      
------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer          | not null default nextval('branch_id_seq'::regclass)
 name             | character(120)   | 
 center_point_lat | double precision | 
 center_point_lng | double precision | 
 center_point     | point            | 
Indexes:
    "branch_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

paul=# create index pt_idx on branch using gist (center_point);
ERROR:  data type point has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working fine when I try:

```
test=# create table test (pt point);
CREATE TABLE
test=# create index pt_idx on test using gist (pt);
CREATE INDEX
```

Are you sure your `point_col` actually *is* of type `point`? Because, if it's a varchar, than it will indeed miserably fail without the btree_gist contrib - and even then it won't be very useful.

Comment: edited my question showing the print screen and me trying to add a index...please tell me i am being stupid :)

Comment: It might be your Postgresql version. (I'm running 9.1-beta, which has additions to gist indexing, so that might be why I'm not getting any errors.)

Comment: That will probably be it i am using 8.1.23 on a Centos 5.5 system. Doing a yum update shows I cant update to the newer postgres version....:(, any ideas as to how it would have been done with 8.1.23. I cant seem to find anywhere info to add the operator classes when creating the index or even which ones i would need to do the polygon/point search lol

Comment: Update: [in 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createindex.html), the documentation's examples suggest that you create an index on `box(point_col, point_col)`.

Comment: PG 8.1 is over 6 years old. That's not just outdated. It's hopelessly so. :-|

Comment: :( i am getting so fu**ing fed up of centos, I know its for stability but everything is just so out of date!!! I have had to update loads manually with no yum so everything gets broke when i do update via yum...guess the thing to do would be to update yet another service manually. What os do you use?

Comment: OSX on the laptop, and FreeBSD on the servers. I'm not too familiar with yum, but maybe try [`yum upgrade yum`](http://superuser.com/questions/67382/yum-cheatsheet-for-macports-users-can-haz) to refresh the package list?

Comment: just spent the last two hours uninstalling postgres and installing postgres 8.4 only to have the same error hahahahahahaha GREAT!

This works though:

create index pt_idx on table using gist (box(point_col, point_col));

Will this have the same effect? basically i will have 1000s of points and want them indexed, will Postgres automatically take care of updating the index as well? as in phppgadmin it has a button in the index list saying 'Reindex'?

thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Yes, the index is maintained automatically. Do look into installing 9.0 though. It's faster and better.

Comment: @user754703, build PostgreSQL from source. Packages for any critical system software is almost always a bad idea. PostgreSQL 9.0 is where you should be starting out... as stated above, 8.1 is really, really stale.